# How to remove web matrix dependency from web platform installer

Tags: webmatrix, web-platform-installer

I wonder how to remove Web Matrix dependecy from web platform installer.
For example, I saw screencast "how to install wordpress with wpi" and there everything was fine without installinb Web Matrix. This IDE sucks, I have Visual Studio installed, so don't want to install any web matrix components.
The same happens on installing blogEngine.net.
Has anybody dealed with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install applications from the Web Application Gallery, Web Platform Installer will default to including WebMatrix if you are on a client OS (like Windows XP, Vista, or 7). This is so most users will be able to do something with the application once installed - assuming they don't have Visual Studio already installed.

Now, if you happen to not need WebMatrix, you can change this behavior - you can click on the Options link from within Web Platform Installer and change "Which Web Server would you like to use?" to IIS instead of WebMatrix - this will prevent the chaining in of WebMatrix.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much, haven't noticed this option. Kinda blind.